# How do I read a String from a File, split it, and create a Vec<&str> in one statement?

Tags: rust

I need help regarding how to convert file input taken as a string to an vector.
I tried

```
let content = fs::read_to_string(file_path).expect("Failed to read input");
let content: Vec<&str> = content.split("\n").collect();
```

This works, but I wanted to convert it to one statement. Something like

```rust
let content: Vec<&str> = fs::read_to_string(file_path)
    .expect("Failed to read input")
    .split("\n")
    .collect();
```

I tried using

```rust
let content: Vec<&str> = match fs::read_to_string(file_path) {
    Ok(value) => value.split("\n").collect(),
    Err(err) => {
        println!("Error Unable to read the file {}", err);
        return ();
    }
};
```

and

```rust
let content: Vec<&str> = match fs::read_to_string(file_path) {
    Ok(value) => value,
    Err(err) => {
        println!("Error Unable to read the file {}", err);
        return ();
    }
}
.split("\n")
.collect();
```

The compiler says that the borrowed values does not live long enough (1st) and value in freed while in use (2nd) (problem with borrowing, scope and ownership).

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:4:26
  |
4 |   let content: Vec<&str> = fs::read_to_string("")
  |  __________________________^
5 | |     .expect("Failed to read input")
  | |___________________________________^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
6 |       .split("\n")
7 |       .collect();
  |                 - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
8 |       
9 |       dbg!(content);
  |            ------- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I still lack much understanding about how to fix them.

Comment: It's impossible to have a `&str` without something like `String`.

Comment: @Cerberus Your point is mostly useful, but (a) the OP *does* "have" a `String` (b) string literals do not have a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *impossible* to do this in one expression. Use two expressions with a `let`, as you already are and as the compiler tells you.

---

The problem is that `split` produces string slices (`&str`) that reference the temporary `String`. That `String` is deallocated at the end of the statement, making the references invalid. Rust is preventing you from introducing memory unsafety:

```rust
fs::read_to_string(file_path)        // Creates a String
    .expect("Failed to read input")
    .split("\n")                     // Takes references into the String
    .collect();                      // String is dropped, invalidating references
```

If you didn't need a `Vec<&str>`, you could have a `Vec<String>`:

```rust
fs::read_to_string(file_path)
    .expect("Failed to read input")
    .split("\n")
    .map(|s| s.to_string())         // Convert &str to String
    .collect();
```

See also:

- [Temporary value dropped while borrowed, but I don't want to do a let](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59193616/155423)
- [Using a `let` binding to increase a values lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26080157/155423)
- ["borrowed value does not live long enough" seems to blame the wrong thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37264396/155423)
- [Why does the compiler tell me to consider using a `let` binding" when I already am?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28893183/155423)
- [Do I need to use a `let` binding to create a longer lived value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59832621/155423)
- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)

Answer (score 3):

You create a `String` with `read_to_string`, but it is not bound to any variable because you are using it right after by using it with `split`. The `String` is the temporary variable mentioned in the error. It is not bound to anything. The `split` function returns references to the contents of the string... but this `String` will be deallocated by the end of the line, because again, it is not bound to a variable.

If you really need to do it in one line, but a bit less efficiently:

```
let content: Vec<String> = fs::read_to_string(file_path)
    .expect("Failed to read input")
    .split("\n")
    .map(|line| line.to_string())
    .collect();
```